# OpenERP 6.1 multiple views with different fields

Tags: odoo, openerp-6

I would like to create different 'kinds' of purchase order forms in OpenERP with different fields in each. Because of the inheritance model, I am assuming I can't inherit multiple children with disjoint fields. So I decided to create a superset child that had all the fields from all types of PO.

I then created different views, containing different fields from the inherited model.

But each of the views shows the same superset.

Please advise if I am doing this the right way or is there no other way but fields_view_get().
Thanks

Code:

```
class purchase_order_hash(osv.osv):
_name = 'purchase.order'
_inherit = 'purchase.order'
_columns={
            'quality_code': fields....,
            'rice_quality': fields....,
            'packing_code': fields....,
            'packing_type': fields....,
            'late_payment': fields.float('Late Payment'),
            'num_bags': fields.integer('Number of Bags'),
            'unit_kg': fields.integer('Unit kg'),
            'rate_': fields.float('Rate', digits=(16,2), help="Rate"),
            'penalty_moisture': fields.float('Moisture Penalty', digits=(16,2), help="Percentage"),
            'penalty_broken': fields.float('Broken Penalty', digits=(16,2), help="Percentage"),
            'num_trucks': fields.integer('Number of Trucks'),
    'test1': fields.integer('Test 1')
          }
purchase_order_hash()
```

(views xml:)

```
        <record id="purchase_order_hash_form" model="ir.ui.view">
                    <field name="name">purchase_order_hash_form</field>
                    <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="1" />
                    <field name="type">form</field>
                    <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form" />
                    <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="origin" select="2" position="after">
                <field name="quality_code"/>
                <field name="rice_quality"/>
                <field name="packing_code"/>
                <field name="packing_type"/>
                <field name="late_payment"/>
                <field name="num_bags"/>
                <field name="unit_kg"/>
                <field name="rate_"/>
                <field name="penalty_moisture"/>
                <field name="penalty_broken"/>
                <field name="num_trucks"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="purchase_order_hash_form_test" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">purchase_order_hash_form_test</field>
        <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="2" />
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="origin" select="2" position="after">
                <field name="test1"/>
            </field>
            <field name="num_trucks" position="replace"/>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_PO_hash">
        <field name="name">action_PO_hash</field>
        <field name="res_model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="purchase_order_hash_form" />
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_PO_hash_test">
        <field name="name">action_PO_hash_test</field>
        <field name="res_model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="purchase_order_hash_form_test" />
    </record>

    <menuitem id="menu_PO_hash" name="menu_PO_hash" action="action_PO_hash" parent="purchase.menu_procurement_management"/>
    <menuitem id="menu_PO_hash_test" name="menu_PO_hash_test" action="action_PO_hash_test" parent="purchase.menu_procurement_management"/>
```

[Update Oct 16, 2012: view.xml - final working code:]

```
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_PO_hash">
        <field name="name">action_PO_hash</field>
        <field name="res_model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_PO_hash_test">
        <field name="name">action_PO_hash_test</field>
        <field name="res_model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window.view" id="action_PO_hash_2">
        <field name="sequence" eval="1"/>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="purchase_order_hash_form"/>
        <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_PO_hash"/>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window.view" id="action_PO_hash_test_2">
        <field name="sequence" eval="1"/>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="purchase_order_hash_form_test"/>
        <field name="act_window_id" ref="action_PO_hash_test"/>
    </record>

    <menuitem id="menu_PO_hash" name="menu_PO_hash" action="action_PO_hash" parent="purchase.menu_procurement_management"/>
    <menuitem id="menu_PO_hash_test" name="menu_PO_hash_test" action="action_PO_hash_test" parent="purchase.menu_procurement_management"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get different form for each action, then you have to create different forms without inheriting the view. Then for each form and tree view you newly create, please specify the window action. For example:

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window.view" id="a_unique_name_as_id">
            <field name="sequence" eval="2"/>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="your_view_ref_id"/><!--use ref="purchase_order_hash_form_test"-->
            <field name="act_window_id" ref="your_action_reference_id"/><!--use ref='action_PO_hash_test'-->
        </record>
```

Comment: I am assuming what you mean is to remove the line that says <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form">. Is that correct? So then to keep the rest of the standard functionality of the standard PO form, I should paste code from that view into each of my forms? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have updated the code again with your suggestion. What is now happening is that when I click on "Create" of the standard Purchase Order, I get "Test1" as the only field on the form. When I click on menu_PO_hash or menu_PO_hash_test it gives an error: it is unable to find the fields e.g. test1, quality_code, etc. in the model. Clicking on menu_PO_hash_2 or menu_PO_hash_test_2 open something completely unrelated. I must be missing something really basic.

Comment: I have just added an example. You have to create act_window view for each of your form/tree

Comment: I'm sorry I can't find any changes in your pasted code. Please re-paste. Please also check my edited view.xml in the question if it correctly follows your example or not. Thanks

Comment: Dont use the 'act_window.view' id as the action menu. You can find a similar example in stock module. please check how stock picking model is shown in 3 different ways for delivery order, internal move and incoming shipment.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I'll update after the R&D. Meanwhile can you please point me to any site or document or book that describe all these hidden features such as act_window_id and act_window tag etc.?

Comment: I didnt find any sites that describes these features. I found it by reading the code. If you find the answer useful, please accept it. Thank you

Comment: Thank God! That did it! I had to remove the ".view" from the model of the main actions. It is now showing the right fields in the right views. Thanks for your guidance. I am marking this as an answer, however I do still need help: I would like to show the standard PO fields along with my customizations. Please correct me but I think I need to copy paste the PO form view code in my views to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

To create different 'kinds' of purchase order forms you have to create different forms without inheriting them and provide reference of those forms in your action.
Write below tag in your action:

```
<field name="view_id" ref="id_of_your_form"/>
```

You can find so many examples in your addons.

To see example go to addons-6.1/account/account_view.xml: find with "view_id"

Comment: I already have this line in the code that I pasted in the question. I am assuming what you mean is to remove the line that says <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form">. Is that correct?  So then to keep the rest of the standard functionality of the standard PO form, I should paste code from that view into each of my forms? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes. You do not have inherit the forms. You need to create new forms as per your requirements for each and every action.

Comment: Am trying that without luck. Have pasted the updated code above. Still shows all PO fields, containing standard PO fields as well as those from both views in both menus.